# How to center images in a slider blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

My posts in my blog have a slider which shows all the pictures within the post. All of the pictures are aligned to the left and I don't know how to fix this problem. I want them to align to the center and am not sure how to do that effectively. 
here is my website:
http://reezyblog.blogspot.co.uk/

heres all the coding related to the slider:

```html
 /* ===[ Slider ]=== */
.homepage-slider {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.homepage-slider .slick-slide .featured-title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 20%;
    left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 40px 30px 50px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
.homepage-slider .slick-slide:hover .featured-title { background: rgba(255,255,255,.9) }
.homepage-slider .slick-slide .featured-title h2 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #111;
}
.homepage-slider .slick-slide .featured-title .featured-date {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.homepage-slider .slick-slide .featured-title .featured-category {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #e1534f;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... You've seemed to have placed your CSS in the HTML block of the code snippet.

Comment: Please add your HTML too

Answer (score 1):

Add this text-align: center to .slick-initialized .slick-slide class just like below

```
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}
```

and make your .slick-slide {display: inline-block;} just like below

```
.slick-slide img {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it did not work I'm afraid, is there a specific place where I need to copy this code?

Comment: @R.Eezy This should work in most cases. Maybe your situation requires a different approach, but we cannot provide a solution with so little information.

Comment: Find in your css file where you write this class .slick-initialized .slick-slide and add text-align: center; after that find out this .slick-slide img class in your css file and change diaplay: block to display: inline-block